# Focus on last item every time a prop is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React and I am doing a chat app. As you now, everytime there is a new message or any event in the chat screen, that last event/item/message should be focus so the user doesn't have to scroll down in order to look for the new event in the chat. As a regular chat app.

Every event is attached to `this.props.chatMessages`.

I already accomplished this behavior but only when the user adds a new message. And I need that functionality for everything, sometimes the chat says

> New user was added to the chat

or

> User XXXXX leaved the chat

so, those are different events, those are informative messages and not regular user messages.

As I mentioned before, every new event is attached to `this.props.chatMessages`

this is what I did in order to focus in the last message when the user sends a message by himself

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
    this.focusOnLastMessage = this.focusOnLastMessage.bind(this);
    ChatActions.connect({ socketUrl : this.props.socket, mode : this.props.mode, room : this.props.room, user : this.props.user });
  }

  addMessage (text) {
    if (text.length) {
      ChatActions.addMessage(text);
      this.focusOnLastMessage();
    }
  }

  focusOnLastMessage () {
    console.log(this.props.chatMessages);
    let lastMessage = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.messages);
    lastMessage.scrollTop = lastMessage.scrollHeight;
  }
```

and in the render method I have something like this

```
chatForm = <ChatForm onAddMessage={this.addMessage} />;
```

here is the full function just in case. Where you see `<ChatItem .../>` is because that is the component to visualize every new event happening in the chat.

```
class ChatView extends React.Component {

  static getStores () {
    return [ ChatStore ];
  }

  static getPropsFromStores () {
    return ChatStore.getState();
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
    this.focusOnLastMessage = this.focusOnLastMessage.bind(this);
    ChatActions.connect({ socketUrl : this.props.socket, mode : this.props.mode, room : this.props.room, user : this.props.user });
  }

  addMessage (text) {
    if (text.length) {
      ChatActions.addMessage(text);
      this.focusOnLastMessage();
    }
  }

  focusOnLastMessage () {
    console.log(this.props.chatMessages);
    let lastMessage = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.messages);
    lastMessage.scrollTop = lastMessage.scrollHeight;
  }

  render () {
    let messages = this.props.chatMessages.map((message) => {
      return <ChatItem info={message.info} me={message.me} player={message.player} message={message.message}
              onNewEvent={this.focusOnLastMessage} />;
    }), chatForm, hr, dealerPlayerMessages, dealerPlayerBox, minusPlusButtons;

    if (this.props.mode === 'player') {
      dealerPlayerMessages = <ul ref="messages">{messages}</ul>;
      hr = <hr />;
      chatForm = <ChatForm onAddMessage={this.addMessage} />;
      dealerPlayerBox = <div>{dealerPlayerMessages}{hr}{chatForm}</div>
    }

    if (this.props.mode === 'dealer') {
      minusPlusButtons = <MinusPlusButtons />
      dealerPlayerMessages = <ul ref="messages">{messages}</ul>;
      dealerPlayerBox = <div> {minusPlusButtons} {dealerPlayerMessages}</div>
    }

    return <div>
      {dealerPlayerBox}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

so, what should I do in order to listen to every change in `this.props.chatMessages` in order to focus on every new item in the chat ?

Comment: how about the `componentWillReceiveProps` life-cycle method?

Comment: @azium I am reading but don't how to adapt it to my code, can you help me ? please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but let's say a new person joins the chat updating `this.props.chatMessages` to contain a new message notifying users about this change. This means that the first lifecycle method is going to fire

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  // do something with new message
}
```

But you need to scroll the message *after* this has been painted to the dom, so luckily there's a life cycle method for that too.

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
  // dom has been updated with new message, scroll your screen!
  this.focusOnLastMessage()
}
```

Edit: You may need to bind this in your constructor to use `this`, but I don't remember. Not all lifecycle methods need it.

[Lifecycle Methods in docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)